# RegEx to Match Phrases and create Capture Groups

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a RegEx and C# pattern that will match a phrase like:

```
Photos of Washington DC taken by Jane Doe
```

Where the capture groups result in "Photos" "Washington DC" and "Jane Doe". Other possibilities would be:

`Videos of Austin taken by Ruby` : Videos, Austin, Ruby

`Photos of Red Bud Dogs taken by Willa Shepherd` :Photos, Red Bud Dogs, Willa Shepherd

Is this even possible with RegEx?

It appears that I got flagged...did I mention that I don't know RegEx?
I tried: `(Photo of).*?((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(Taken by)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))` but that failed.

Comment: Sure is! Try looking up the `.Matches` method.

Comment: yes, this is possible. I normally use this site when building more complex expressions: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Thanks Leon, though I don't understand the tool. I tried to paste in the result from Tim below, but the matches don't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` matches any string (except newlines). By adding a `?` to it (`.*?`), you can tell the regex engine to match as few characters as possible, which is probably the right approach here, so the very first instances of `of` and `taken by` will be used as separators of your intended sub-matches:

```
matchResults = Regex.Match(subjectString, "^(.*?) of (.*?) taken by (.*)");
// matchResults.Groups[1].Value contains "Photos" etc.
```

If you don't expect more than one  `of` and `taken by`  in your input, you can change all `.*?` into `.*`.

Comment: ...and your answer is condescending, but it works, thanks.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott: Sorry about that - your initial question didn't show where your problem was, it came across a bit like "I don't feel like reading a basic [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), please write some code for me" - which lead to my rather blunt answer. Your edited question is much better, and I will try and improve my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sweet, thanks, I have been at this for days, RegEx is a real mystery to me. Even after applying your solution I don't truely understand it. Then testing it is even harder.